# ASP C# CheckBox within DetailsView

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

I have a DetailsView in my aspx page with two check boxes in item template columns. I have a buttoun outside DetailsView. What i need is when i click button it should verify whether both checkboxes are checked and fire c# command. please help. Let me paste Code below:

.aspx

```
 <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button3_Click" />
    </div>
    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView2" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
        <Fields>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="StudentName" SortExpression="StudentName">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StudentName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email">

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Email") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
```

C#

```
 protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A `DetailsView` is a data bound control which can hold an unlimited number of rows, not just one.

If you want to verify both checkboxes are checked, in each row, you would need to iterate through all of the `DetailsView`'s rows, and cast the `CheckBox` from `FindControl` on each row:

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < DetailsView2.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        CheckBox chk1 = (CheckBox)DetailsView2.Rows[i].FindControl("CheckBox1");
        CheckBox chk2 = (CheckBox)DetailsView2.Rows[i].FindControl("CheckBox2");

        if (chk1.Checked && chk2.Checked)
        {
           // Do Stuff
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to verify **all** checkboxes are checkes in **all rows**, do this:

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Declare a boolean flag
    bool AllCheckBoxesAreChecked = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < DetailsView2.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        CheckBox chk1 = (CheckBox)DetailsView2.Rows[i].FindControl("CheckBox1");
        CheckBox chk2 = (CheckBox)DetailsView2.Rows[i].FindControl("CheckBox2");

        if (!chk1.Checked || !chk2.Checked)
            AllCheckBoxesAreChecked = false;
    }

    // Now use the flag
    if (AllCheckBoxesAreChecked)
    {
        // Do Stuff
    }
}
```